# cannot connect to repository from configured remote. you would want to check .git config

Tags: android, github

I tried sharing my repository to Github in Android Studio & I get this message:

> "Can't connect to the repository from the configured remote. You could want to check .git config"

If I ignore and share, Github creates an empty repository and won't upload git files. I reinstalled GitHub and created a link to git.exe in Android Studio and removed repositories with the same name on Github. But again the same message appears. So, how do I create a repository and push files on GitHub? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: see this link https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

Answer (score 12):

*I tried all the above suggestion, but nothing works for me.*
What did work for me is "**open your code editor, delete the remote origins files under vcs > git > remotes...**" - the step-by-step process is given below

**Step-by-step process:**

1) Delete the repository from GitHub

2) Open android studio.

3) Load the file on which you were working.

4) Click on - VCS > Git > Remotes... >

5) Git remotes will popup.

6) Select the file, and click on (-) red minus sign.

7) Remove remote origins

8) Click on yes

done.
now you can proceed to upload your code to the GitHub
....happy coding

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same problem yesterday. I've tried to reset AS and reinstalling Git but that, unfortunately, doesn't help, as the message keeps coming back

For some reason, when I change Git to < none > in File > Setting > Version Control, the message magically vanished when I go after that to Import into Version Control > Share Project in Github!

I was able to share my project to Github and doing all CVS operations successfully after that simple change!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the git directory like Users/username/.git/config which has like remote["origin"], (you will find it seems like what you wanna to drop it.)

By the way, the .git is a hidden directory. You may need to do some setting.

just delete the remote like the sample:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/ReZeroS/Smtp.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And you should get like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these simple steps:**

*1. VCS => Git => Remotes*
*2. There would be one or more origins present of your remote VCS', hit that `-` sign to remove all origins of `github`*
*3.Now all the origins of github have been removed. Now try to import your project on github again. this time it will surely work.*

Answer (score 0):

Show hidden files in your project. Open .git/config. Copy any config file from another VCS/git project (that works with GIT correctly), change 'url' key in it to appropriate https link (as your current project on github). That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the .ignore plugin and the problem was solved

Answer (score -1):

Check the git directory like Users/username/.git/config which has like remote["origin"], (you will find it seems like what you wanna to drop it.)
By the way, the .git is a hidden directory. You may need to do some setting.
    just delete the remote like the sample:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/ReZeroS/Smtp.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
And you should get like this:
   [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

If the above does not work, delete the ".gitignore" file from your project gradle