# Share android project in Github creates empty project

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github) to share my project. I happen to have a volley library in my project. But I only see the library in my github account and not my project. I am on Android studio 2.2.3. Obviously, the git and github test from Android studio is working(successful). I tried this many times but each time my whole project is missing except the Volley library. Has anyone encountered the similar problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Downvoter should have explained a SO rule, if I any, you feel I violated. What you did is simply childish act that doesn't conform to the values of this site.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Android Studio, you have to create the repository as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

Then from that same selection you select "share project on Github". After that you simply select CVS-> Commit Changes each time you make changes to the file. The first step is missing in all of the SO answers and online tutorials available online today.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old post but I came across this post when I had similar issues. I tried to share android project and it kept creating empty file.
I tried to run git add . on my local repository but like you it only pushed one activity and when I tried to push again it kept giving me cannot connect to repository error. This is another stack link that helped me I followed the steps given by Aditya Anand on this link : 
[cannot connect to repository from configured remote. you would want to check .git config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841385/cannot-connect-to-repository-from-configured-remote-you-would-want-to-check-gi)

steps:

Step-by-step process:

1) Delete the repository from GitHub

2) Open android studio.

3) Load the file on which you were working.

4) Click on - VCS > Git > Remotes... >

5) Git remotes will popup.

6) Select the file, and click on (-) red minus sign.

7) Remove remote origins

8) Click on yes

After I followed those steps I went ahead and run the git add . command again. Then from android studio I pushed the project which successfully pushed all the files. Hope this helps.